# How to output text and delete text with buttons

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to output text from button presses and add it to a textbox each time it's pressed as well as delete the text when the delete button is pressed - in normal python.

I've been trying to use `kivy.uix.textinput`, but I'm not sure on how to output the value from the buttons as well as delete it.

This is what I've done so far.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class CodeScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CodeScreen, self).__init__(name='code_screen')

        main_grid_lay = GridLayout(cols=2,cols_minimum={0:640, 1:175})
        self.add_widget(main_grid_lay)

        #Code ouput display
        display_code = TextInput(text='Code!', readonly = True, id=output)
        main_grid_lay.add_widget(display_code)                                    

        #Options Buttons
        box_lay = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')                                 
        main_grid_lay.add_widget(box_lay)

        delete_button = Button(                                                     
            text='Delete',
            size_hint_x= None,
            width=160,
            id=''           #unsure on how to delete
        )
        box_lay.add_widget(delete_button)
        base_left = Button(
            text='Base Left',
            #on_release= b_left(),
            #id='left',
        )
        base_right = Button(
            text='Base Right',
            on_release=self.degree_popup,
            #on_release= b_right(),
        )

        #b_left = self.ids.output.text='left'
        #b_left = self.ids.output.text='right'
        box_lay.add_widget(base_left)
        box_lay.add_widget(base_right)

# The app class
class MyMain(App):
    def build(self):
        return CodeScreen()

# Runs the App
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyMain().run()
```

It currently sends an error and is probably because of the ids. Not fully sure how ids work without using kv language. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Ids work only in kv. Read [here](https://blog.kivy.org/2019/06/widget-interactions-between-python-and-kv/) an article about ["Widget interactions between Python and Kv"](https://blog.kivy.org/2019/06/widget-interactions-between-python-and-kv/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id only makes sense in .kv, in python they are useless. In this case the solution is to access the objects in the methods connected to on_release but for this they must be class attributes.

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class CodeScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CodeScreen, self).__init__(name="code_screen")

        self.display_code = TextInput(text="Code!", readonly=True)

        self.delete_button = Button(
            text="Delete", size_hint_x=None, width=160, on_release=self.delete_clicked
        )

        self.base_left = Button(text="Base Left", on_release=self.left_clicked)
        self.base_right = Button(text="Base Right", on_release=self.right_clicked)

        main_grid_lay = GridLayout(cols=2, cols_minimum={0: 640, 1: 175})
        main_grid_lay.add_widget(self.display_code)
        self.add_widget(main_grid_lay)
        box_lay = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
        box_lay.add_widget(self.delete_button)
        main_grid_lay.add_widget(box_lay)

        box_lay.add_widget(self.base_left)
        box_lay.add_widget(self.base_right)

    def delete_clicked(self, instance):
        self.display_code.text = ""

    def left_clicked(self, instance):
        self.display_code.text += "left"

    def right_clicked(self, instance):
        self.display_code.text += "right"


# The app class
class MyMain(App):
    def build(self):
        return CodeScreen()


# Runs the App
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMain().run()
```